# How to pass data from MainActivity to ViewModel in Xamarin MVVMCross?

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to pass data from searchView query to my ViewModel, but I can't find way to do that. I want to pass searchText to variable in ViewModel. Any suggestion would be great, thanks! ;)

MainActivity

```
public class MainAcitvityView : MvxActivity<MoviesViewModel>
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
              SearchView search = FindViewById<SearchView>(Resource.Id.searchview);
              search.QueryHint = "Search movie title..";
                search.QueryTextSubmit += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    var searchText = e.NewText;
                    MoviesViewModel.SearchText = searchText
    
                };
```

I tried MoviesViewModel.SearchText = searchText
but I got error :
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MoviesViewModel.SearchText'

Answer (score 0):

When you use `MvxActivity<MoviesViewModel>` you can access the `ViewModel` property rather than try to access your ViewModel statically, exactly like the error you are getting is telling you.

So just change from:

```
MoviesViewModel.SearchText = searchText;
```

To:

```
ViewModel.SearchText = searchText;
```